# Basic website navigation

Tags: winforms, web, navigation

I want to make a program that when given a list of username and passwords, will go to a website, login, and interact with the website (click a couple buttons, etc.) for each username/password combination given.

I was wondering if the community had any suggestion on where to start (language/platform-wise)?
I have very little experience in programming with/for the web, and my program seems simple enough to not need any complex architecture. I would prefer to program it with a Windows Form since the person I'm giving the program too won't be too experienced in anything computer-related.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my tutorial/blog about the [simplest MVC ever](http://www.ganymedes.be/index/blog/2). It has a live example, and you can download the source code, or build it yourself from the example.

Answer (score 1):

The Best and simple approach to do the task is using 
**CURL** Library of **PHP** Language.
You could take the help of this [Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/techniques-and-resources-for-mastering-curl/) Page.